# How to get deep key in array php?

Tags: php, arrays

If a have an array:

```
Array
(
    [1-title1] => Array
        (
            [0] => title = title erer
            [1] => 1-title1
            [2] => content = content 1
        )

    [2-title2] => Array
        (
            [0] => title = title dffgfghfdg
            [1] => 2-title2
            [2] => content = content 2
        )
```

and I want to get array:

```
Array
(
    [1-title1] => Array
        (
            [title] =>title erer
            [1] =>title1
            [content] =>content 1
        )

    [2-title2] => Array
        (
            [title] =>title dffgfghfdg
            [2] => title2
            [content] =>content 2
        )
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

A solution without references and no implicit key names.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $innerArray) {
    foreach ($innerArray as $innerKey => $value) {
        if (false !== strpos($value, ' = ')) {
            unset($array[$key][$innerKey]);
            list($innerKey, $value) = explode(' = ', $value, 2);
            $array[$key][$innerKey] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($array as $ky=>$val)  {
  echo $ky;
  var_dump(array_keys($val));
}
```

Comment: Why iterate? `var_dump(array_keys($array))`.

Comment: i am try but i got

1-title1
2-title2
3-title3
4-title4

Comment: @Kenaniah because array_keys returns only parent key and if he wants to get title etc, he ca use array_keys

Comment: @Robin, I get that, but your answer only references the keys. What you literally posted didn't use values at all.

Comment: @Robin, if I had a penny for every person I met who was as rude as you are, I'd probably have a penny.

Comment: @Kenaniah oh sorry, sorry Its my mistake , I should mention 'Joe Merra'. By mistake I have mentioned you. Yes, The way you told is correct. My answer was another way that will easily understand by beginners.

Comment: all..i am so sorry n thanks..i am new n beginner in PHP. so i need your support!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as &$title){
    $newTitle = array();
    $titleName = explode(' = ', $title[0] , 2);
    $newTitle['title'] = end($titleName);
    $titleNum = explode('-', $title[1] , 2);
    $newTitle[$titleNum[0]] = $titleNum[1];
    $titleContent = explode(' = ', $title[2] , 2);
    $newTitle['content'] = end($titleContent);  
    $title = $newTitle;
}
```